# mongodb driver does not free resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

My mocha test does not exist when the mongodb driver fails to connect (*because the db is offline for instance*).

**How can I free up the resource to make the test exit?** The client is null therefore I cannot use `client.close()`.
I know there is the `--exit` mocha flag, but I'd like to close the mongo driver.
Thank you!

my code is like:

```
static async create(
    dbName: string = db_name,
    url: string = db_url,
  ): Promise<MongoDbContext> {
    return new Promise<MongoDbContext>((resolve, reject) => {
      mongodb.MongoClient.connect(
        url,
        {
          keepAlive: 1000,
          connectTimeoutMS: 1000,
          socketTimeoutMS: 1000,
        },
        function(err, client) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return reject(err)
          }
          console.log('Connected successfully to server')
          resolve(new MongoDbContext(client, dbName))
        },
      )
    })
  }
```

spec

```
 it('should throw if error occures', async function() {
    this.timeout(1000)
    try {
      mongo = await MongoDbContext.create('artifact_test')
    } catch (error) {
      return
    }
    fail('there was no exception')
  })
```

**Update:**
now it terminates after a specific time but did not figure out which option has an effect on it, because in the example everything is set 1000ms but it's still longer

Comment: Have you tried invoking connect [with options](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect), specifically `connectTimeoutMS` and `socketTimeoutMS`?

Comment: good idea, I'm trying 
      ` {
          keepAlive: 1000,
          connectTimeoutMS: 2000,
          socketTimeoutMS: 2000,
          socketOptions: {
            connectTimeoutMS: 2000,
            socketTimeoutMS: 2000,
          },
        }, `

but neither works

Comment: Can you post the updated code with the options? Also what's your mocha test timeout? By default it is 2 sec. Which is the same connection timeout you use here.

Comment: you were right the solution was in the config, thank you! updated the post

Comment: Great news! Please post it as an answer to your own question and accept it, rather than adding it in the question. That way others having same issue would be able to locate it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

The client was trying to reconnect, so you need to set the following config property:

```
{
   autoReconnect: false
}
```